# Nesting an array of objects in javascript by matching details

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects and some of the objects shares the same id, is there a quick way to nest them so they can be grouped, such as from:

```
var items = [
               { id: 5,   title: 'wow',        name: 'item1' },
               { id: 5,   title: 'wow',        name: 'item2' },
               { id: 26,  title: 'latest',     name: 'item3' },
               { id: 26,  title: 'latest',     name: 'item4' }
            ];
```

To:

```
 var items = [
               [{ id: 5,   title: 'wow',        name: 'item1' },
                { id: 5,   title: 'wow',        name: 'item2' } ],
               [{ id: 26,  title: 'latest',     name: 'item3' },
                { id: 26,  title: 'latest',     name: 'item4' } ]
            ];
```

When you don't have any details about those objects in advance, i could use simple loops for that but i am looking for a shorter, smart solution if there is one, something like: for each in items group by the same id's under arrays or something.

Comment: There are "smart" solutions but did you try the obvious loop ? What's the problem ?

Comment: SO shouldn't be just where lazy coders asks for people to write their easy 10 lines of code. There should be an explicit difficulty.

Comment: There is no problem doing it using simple loops. I am looking for a shorter, smart solution as you say, something like: for each in items group by the same id's under arrays or something.

Comment: Then you should have been explicit about the real question.

Comment: It's not a matter of laziness.

Comment: You didn't include any of your own code in the question tho, did you?

Comment: I didn't see myself copying your answer yet, tho. that is quite easy to do by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for the sake of diversity, you have two good loops solutions. Here is one with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (although, using reduce like this maybe not that smart actually):

```js
var items = [
    { id: 5,   title: 'wow',        name: 'item1' },
    { id: 5,   title: 'wow',        name: 'item2' },
    { id: 26,  title: 'latest',     name: 'item3' },
    { id: 26,  title: 'latest',     name: 'item4' }
];

var result = items.reduce(function(prev, curr, index, array) {
    
    if (!prev.cache[curr.id]) {
        prev.data.push(prev.cache[curr.id] = []);
    }
    
    prev.cache[curr.id].push(curr);
    
    return index === array.length - 1 ? prev.data : prev;
    
}, {data: [], cache: {}});
    
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: It'll be interesting to know if the OP actually understands this code rather than just choosing it for being functionally "smart".

Comment: @Andy I hope he does, but I don't think it's too hard to understand it if one reads documentation on `reduce`. If not, I can easily explain it if necessary. It actually just uses intermediate object like you do in your example, just in my case `temp` and `out` are within `reduce` loop (`{data: [], cache: {}}`). On the final iteration (`index === array.length - 1`) this `prev.data` is returned. That's it, not that fancy after all.

Comment: One thing that intrigued me - I didn't realise you could do this: `prev.data.push(prev.cache[curr.id] = []);`. I learned something new today :)

Comment: @Andy Well this is interesting, yes. It makes use of the fact that objects are passed by reference. So if `prev.cache[curr.id]` is not yet there we need to create an empty array to push items in it. We also need to push this new array into `prev.data` because `prev.data` is the array to be returned in the end. So we could do it like this `prev.cache[curr.id] = []; prev.data.push(rev.cache[curr.id])`. Or we can do it shorted, because `=` operator returns a value it just assigned, i.e. new array referencing the one just pushed into `prev.data`.

Answer (score 1):

Use an object to temporarily store the objects where the key is the id, then loop over the temporary object adding the stored objects to an output array:

```
function group(items){
    var temp = {};
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
        var id = items[i].id;
        if (!temp[id]) temp[id] = [];
        temp[id].push(items[i]);
    }
    for (var p in temp) {
      out.push(temp[p]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xa4239nd/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function groupBy(array, f) {
    var groups = {};
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        var group = JSON.stringify(f(o));
        groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
        groups[group].push(o);
    });
    return Object.keys(groups).map(function (group) {
        return groups[group];
    })
}

var groupedById = groupBy(items, function (item) {
    return [item.id];
});
console.log(groupedById)
```